# How to determine what the affinity/anti-affinity of programmatically created pod are?

Tags: kubernetes

We are having issues that rarely we will have a pod fail to be scheduled with an error that all 16 nodes failed due to affinity/anti-affinity.  We would not expect affinity to prevent any of the nodes from being scheduled.

I'd like to determine what the actual cause of the affinity failing in scheduling is, and for that I think I need to know what the affinities a pod was initialized with.  However, I can't look at chart configuration files since these particular pods are being scheduled programmatically at runtime.  Is there a kubectl command I can use to view what the pod's affinity was set to, or to determine why every node is failing its affinity checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out on my own.  The command I used was:

```
kubectl get pods <pod_name> -o json | jq '.spec.affinity'
```

I had to yum install jq for this to work.  if instead you wanted to look at affinity of all pods I think you need to remove the pod name and add a .items[] in front of the .spec for the jq command.

For those curious my affinity has this

```
{ 
  "key": "host",
  "operator": "In",
  "values": [
     "yes"
  ]
}
```

That "yes" doesn't seem quite right to me.  So yeah something funky is happening in our pod creation.